# MapBox user location icon | iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, mapbox

I want to customize user location image. Avatar of user need to be instead classic blue dot. Do someone have any ideas how can i do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of how to customize the `MGLUserLocationAnnotationView` is available on the iOS examples page: https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/maps/examples/user-location-annotation/